# Add two textbox values and display the sum in a third textbox automatically

Tags: javascript

I have assigned a task to add two textbox values.I want the result of addition to appear in the 3rd textbox,as soon as enter the values in the first two textboxes,without pressing any buttons.

For eg:In the first textbox i want to enter 450,when i press digit 4 of number '450',then it will be added to the 3rd textbox,any number i press in the first two textboxes,suddenly that changes will be reflected on the third textbox.How can i do this?

Here i write my code call sum() in onkeyup

```
onkeyup="sum()"
function sum() {
        var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
        var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
        var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
        if(!isNaN(result)){
            document.getElementById('txt3').value = result;
        }
}
```

This is not working in chrome

Comment: What kind of error you are getting in chrome? Did you check browser console?

Comment: what is the output of `result` in chrome? Try `console.log(result)`

Comment: Dhaval Marthak-In chrome no result will be displayed in Third textbox.In my code the reult will display only after enter values in 2nd textbox.but i want any number i entered in any 2 texbox suddenly that change will be reflected on 3rd textbox

Comment: @Monica i know that what you want, but there should be something in error console of chorme. i want that `error`

Comment: Did you add the event (keyup) to both textboxes or the second one? How does you textbox markup look like? Have you checked the console of your browser for any error?

Comment: codingbiz-(keyup) event used in both textboxes

Comment: @Monica I have posted my answer with demo. have a look at it

Comment: @Monica please look at the solution I've posted

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try this

```
  function sum() {
       var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
       var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
       if (txtFirstNumberValue == "")
           txtFirstNumberValue = 0;
       if (txtSecondNumberValue == "")
           txtSecondNumberValue = 0;

       var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
       if (!isNaN(result)) {
           document.getElementById('txt3').value = result;
       }
   }
```

Comment: becareful if u use server textbox , u must use getElementById('<%=txt1.ClientID%>') instead of getElementById('txt1')

Comment: I want to change the line 'var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);' to 'var result = (parseFloat(txtFirstNumberValue)/parseFloat("100")) * parseFloat(txtSecondNumberValue);' but it is not showing any result. please help

Answer (score 10):

Try this: Open given fiddle in **CHROME**

```
function sum() {
      var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
      var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
      var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
      if (!isNaN(result)) {
         document.getElementById('txt3').value = result;
      }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="txt1"  onkeyup="sum();" />
<input type="text" id="txt2"  onkeyup="sum();" />
<input type="text" id="txt3" />
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tLKLy/)

Comment: you're answer is exactly what @monica did!! please re read the question then edit your answer

Comment: @MuhammadRamahy _I have assigned a task to add two textbox values.I want the result of addition to appear in the 3rd textbox,as soon as enter the values in the first two textboxes,without pressing any buttons._ and please can you explain the portion for EG:

Comment: *In my code the reult will display only after enter values in 2nd textbox.but i want any number i entered in any 2 texbox suddenly that change will be reflected on 3rd textbox* this was ironically reply to you but you didn't pay attention to comments

Answer (score 2):

i didn't find who made elegant answer , that's why let me say :

```
Array.from(
   document.querySelectorAll('#txt1,#txt2')
).map(e => parseInt(e.value) || 0) // to avoid NaN
.reduce((a, b) => a+b, 0)
```

```js
window.sum= () => 
 document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=    
   Array.from(
     document.querySelectorAll('#txt1,#txt2')
   ).map(e=>parseInt(e.value)||0)
   .reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0)
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="sum()"/>
<input type="text" id="txt2" onkeyup="sum()"  style="margin-right:10px;"/><span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, base on your code, you would put **onkeyup=sum()** in each text box **txt1 and txt2**

Comment: i already use this.but when i enter value in txt1 only,then no result will display

Comment: It means when you enter value in **txt1** and no value in **txt2** and you won't get the result since the value of txt2 is empty :).

Answer (score 0):

well I think the problem solved
this below code works:

```
function sum() {
    var result=0;
       var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
       var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
    if (txtFirstNumberValue !="" && txtSecondNumberValue ==""){
        result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue);
    }else if(txtFirstNumberValue == "" && txtSecondNumberValue != ""){
        result= parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
    }else if (txtSecondNumberValue != "" && txtFirstNumberValue != ""){
        result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
    }
       if (!isNaN(result)) {
           document.getElementById('txt3').value = result;
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code

```
function sum() 
{ 
    var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('total_fees').value; 
    var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('advance_payement').value; 
    var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) - parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue); 
    if(txtFirstNumberValue=="" ||txtSecondNumberValue=="") 
    { 
        document.getElementById('balance_payement').value = 0; 
    }
    if (!isNaN(result)) 
    { 
        document.getElementById('balance_payement').value = result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `eval("3+2")=5` ,you can use it as following :

```
byId=(id)=>document.getElementById(id); 
byId('txt3').value=eval(`${byId('txt1').value}+${byId('txt2').value}`)
```

By that,  you don't need  `parseInt`

Answer (score 0):

In below code i have done operation of sum and subtraction: because of using **JavaScript** if you want to call function, then you have to put your below code outside of `document.ready(function{ });` and outside the script end tag.

I have taken one another script tag for this operation.And put below code between script starting tag  // your code //  script ending tag.

```
 function operation() 

 {

   var txtFirstNumberValue = parseInt(document.getElementById('basic').value);
   var txtSecondNumberValue =parseInt(document.getElementById('hra').value);
   var txtThirdNumberValue =parseInt(document.getElementById('transport').value);
   var txtFourthNumberValue =parseInt(document.getElementById('pt').value);
   var txtFiveNumberValue = parseInt(document.getElementById('pf').value);

   if (txtFirstNumberValue == "")
       txtFirstNumberValue = 0;
   if (txtSecondNumberValue == "")
       txtSecondNumberValue = 0;
   if (txtThirdNumberValue == "")
       txtThirdNumberValue = 0;
   if (txtFourthNumberValue == "")
       txtFourthNumberValue = 0;
   if (txtFiveNumberValue == "")
       txtFiveNumberValue = 0;



   var result = ((txtFirstNumberValue + txtSecondNumberValue + 
  txtThirdNumberValue) - (txtFourthNumberValue + txtFiveNumberValue));
   if (!isNaN(result)) {
       document.getElementById('total').value = result;
   }
 }
```

And put `onkeyup="operation();"` inside all 5 textboxes in your html form. 
This code running in both Firefox and Chrome.