# How to Add Two Input Values And Show In The Third Input Box ?? with simple JavaScript like this help me where i was wrong

Tags: javascript, php, html

1)I want to add the values of two input boxes and show it in the third input. It shows an error

2)Error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
at sum (js.php:21)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (js.php:12)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>JavaScript</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function sum() {
        var val1 = document.getElementById('val1').value;
        var val2 = document.getElementById('val2').value;
        var sum = val1 + val1;
        document.getElementById('total').value = sum;
      }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="text" name="val1"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="val2"><br><br>
    <input disabled name="total" value=""><br><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="sum()" name="btn">Add</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

I expected the sum of two inputs but it shows nothing.

Comment: correct it like this   <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1"><br><br>

Comment: now, you have all the answers below :)

Comment: check this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/16668731/5326667

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the attribute *id* for the controls which you are referencing in your code with `getElementById()`. You also have to convert the string value to number to perform the arithmetic operation:

```js
function sum(){
  var val1 = document.getElementById('val1').value;
  var val2 = document.getElementById('val2').value;
  var sum = Number(val1) + Number(val2);
  document.getElementById('total').value = sum;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="val1" id="val1"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="val2" id="val2"><br><br>
<input name="total" id="total" value=""><br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="sum()" name="btn">Add</button>
```

Comment: It works. I forgot to Add IDs To HTML Elements, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByName` returns a NodeList of elements so it doesn't have property `.value`.

This is `getElementsByName` snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>JavaScript</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function sum() {

      var val1 = document.getElementsByName('val1')[0].value;
      var val2 = document.getElementsByName('val2')[0].value;
      var sum = parseInt(val1) + parseInt(val2); // by default it appends a string. Hence, parseInt to parse string to integer

      document.getElementsByName('total')[0].value = sum;
      console.log(document.getElementsByName('total')[0].value);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" name="val1"><br><br>
  <input type="text" name="val2"><br><br>
  <input type="hidden" name="total" value=""><br><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="sum()" name="btn">Add</button>
</body>

</html>
```

This is `getElementById` snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>JavaScript</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function sum() {
      var val1 = document.getElementById('val1').value;
      var val2 = document.getElementById('val2').value;
      var sum = parseInt(val1) + parseInt(val1); // by default it appends a string. Hence, parseInt to parse string to integer

      document.getElementById('total').value = sum;
      console.log(document.getElementById('total').value);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1"><br><br>
  <input type="text" name="val2" id="val2"><br><br>
  <input type="hidden" name="total" value="" id="total"><br><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="sum()" name="btn">Add</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I get a lot of confusions but you clear my conclusions by comparing getElementsByName and getElementById , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should add Id to your input. You use `getElementById`, but your input doesn't have any `id`, so it will retourn null.

```
<input type="text" name="val1" id="val1"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="val2" id="id="val2"><br><br>
<input type="hidden"  name="total" value="" id="total"><br><br>
```

Comment: Thanks For Explanation, I Forget To Add IDs

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<script>
 function sum(){
        var val1 = document.getElementById('val1').value;
        var val2 = document.getElementById('val2').value;
        var sum = +val1 + +val2;
       document.getElementById('total').value = sum;
      }  
</script>

<body>
    <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="val2" id="val2"><br><br>
     <input type="hidden"  name="total" id="total" value=""><br><br>
     <button type="button" onclick="sum()" name="btn">Add</button>
   </body>
```

OR Fetch through name

```
<script>
 function sum(){
        var val1 = document.getElementsByName('val1')[0].value;
        var val2 = document.getElementsByName('val2')[0].value;
        var sum = +val1 + +val2;
       document.getElementsByName('total')[0].value = sum;
      }  
</script>

<body>
    <input type="text" name="val1" ><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="val2" ><br><br>
     <input type="hidden"  name="total" value=""><br><br>
     <button type="button" onclick="sum()" name="btn">Add</button>
   </body>
```

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt : Please Have look.

Comment: It works. I forgot to Add IDs To HTML Elements, Thanks.

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer IMHO. Please refer [answer]

Answer (score 0):

You are using **`HTML DOM getElementById() Method`**, so you should assign an Id to your input **total** in order to resolve the issue:

```
<input type="hidden" name="total" id="total" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with click on button to sum of two input value OR with use of onblur events also

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                function sum(){
                  var val_1 = document.getElementById('val1').value;
                  var val_2 = document.getElementById('val2').value;
                  var sum = Number(val_1) + Number(val_2);
                  document.getElementById('total').value = sum;
                }
                </script>

                <input type="text" id="val1" onblur="sum()"><br><br>
                <input type="text" id="val2" onblur="sum()"><br><br>
                <input id="total" value=""><br><br>
                <button type="button" onclick="sum()" name="btn">Add</button>
```

Comment: It works. I forgot to Add IDs To HTML Elements, Thanks
and iam also searching for onblur event thanks for extra information

Comment: @samad  Yes definitely help onblur events, and  Your Welcome...

Answer (score 0):

You should use id attribute to get the input value which you are referencing in your code with getElementById().

and You also have to convert the string value to number to perform the arithmetic operation because when we get value from inputs it will a string value

for convert string to number you can use + sign like in code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JavaScript</title>     
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function sum(){
      var val1 = +document.getElementById('val1').value;
      var val2 = +document.getElementById('val2').value;
      document.getElementById('total').value = val1+val2;
    }     
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1"><br><br>
  <input type="text" name="val2" id="val2"><br><br>
    <input type="hidden"  name="total" id="total" value=""><br><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="sum()" name="btn">Add</button>

  </body>
</html>
```