# after the value is assigned to the variable "NaN" the value does not change

Tags: javascript, html

Why is there not assigned value in the line `val3.value = parseInt(val1.value + val2.value);` the specified value "NaN" cannot be parsed, or is out of range?

```js
var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1"));
var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2"));
var val3 = document.getElementById("num3");

document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function() {
  val3.value = parseInt(val1.value + val2.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="num1" />
<input type="number" id="num2" />
<input type="number" readonly id="num3" /> <br />
<button id="add">add</button>
```

the output value not assigned

Comment: You're trying to parse elements, not their values. Those values should be read in the event listener, not outside of it.

Comment: Probably Duplicate of [Add two textbox values and display the sum in a third textbox automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16668752/7738489)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```js
const val1 = document.getElementById("num1");
const val2 = document.getElementById("num2");
const val3 = document.getElementById("num3");

document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function() {
  val3.value = val1.valueAsNumber + val2.valueAsNumber;
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="num1" />
<input type="number" id="num2" />
<input type="number" readonly id="num3" /> <br />
<button id="add">add</button>
```

Your code has some fatal flaws:

- You try to parse [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)s as a string which won't work and it's not what you want to do
- When you have two strings (which two [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#value)s of inputs are) using `+` the values will be concatenated, not added meaning `"2" + "2"` will be `"22"`, not `4`.

```js
console.log("2" + "2");
console.log(2 + 2)
```

```css
/* Stackoverflow: show only console */
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
    top: 0;
}
```

To address this you want to do two things:

- remove the [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) on the HTML elements
- use [`valueAsNumber`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#valueasnumber) instead of [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#value) since this will give you the value of the `<input />` element as a `number` hence eliminating the need to manually parse the number and doing a concatenation instead of an addition.

Last but not least, generally, consider using `const` or `let` instead of `var`, since `var` always declares global variables, which you can cause all kinds of weird problems and bugs once your program grows in size. See [Difference between var, let and const keywords in JavaScript](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-var-let-and-const-keywords-in-javascript/)

Comment: Note you can only use valueAsNumber on fields that have number as output. So not a text field

Answer (score -1):

Replace the script with the following :

```
<script>
  var val1 = document.getElementById("num1");
  var val2 = document.getElementById("num2");
  var val3 = document.getElementById("num3");

  document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function () {
    val3.value = val1.valueAsNumber + val2.valueAsNumber;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to get the values in the `click` listener otherwise you'll just end up with the initial value for `val1` and `val2` no matter what the user enters.